# Qt Threads and the default QSQLDatabase connection (sqlite)

Tags: qt, sqlite, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

Is it safe to use default database connection from different threads? Like this:

```
bool upSafe(const QString &mig_to, const QString &mig_from) const {
  if (!QSqlDatabase::database().transaction()) {
    qCCritical(hfCoreMT) << "Failed init database transaction";
    return false;
  }

  if (!up(mig_to, mig_from)) {
    QSqlDatabase::database().rollback();
    return false;
  }

  return QSqlDatabase::database().commit();
}
```

In function `up` default QSQLQuery created and executed. Maybe some hints to the right pattern?

Comment: read this: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.11.0/?h=v5.11.0#n231

Comment: What do you mean by 'different'?

Comment: @eyllanesc should I interpret is as: "It should be safe but till 5.11 there was a bug" ?

Comment: Your example shows single thread usage.

Comment: @Michał Walenciak usage is similar for other threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSqlDatabase (which represents one DB connection) is not reentrant. You can use a connection only from the thread you created it. If you need to perform queries from another thread you need to create another connection from that thread first.

Comment: So the answer is "No".  Default connection as any connectoin should be used only in thread where it have been opened.